# Should I request audit grading for my MTH 111 class or just fail it?

Tags: mathematics, grading

I’m a freshman attending a community college. I’m taking 17 credits, 5 of which are from my MTH 111 class. I have struggled with sepsis and infection over the past year and got sick in the middle of the term, causing me to fall behind in due dates and information in the class. It is too late for me to withdraw from or drop the class, however in the grading options I have an option between A-F grading or Audit grading. I have no idea what to do and I need advice. Should I change the grading style or just fail the class?

Comment: You should ask your advisor, who will be familiar with the rules at your college.  These rules differ from college to college.  (Do ask about the medical withdrawal possibility though!)

Comment: Should this be tagged US? It seems like it is very specific about their system.

Answer (score 3):

Many institutions allow a hardship withdrawal after the deadline.  Check with the registrar's office.  You will likely have to produce documentation that you were treated by a doctor.

If a hardship withdrawal is not available, ask what changing to audit grading will do to your GPA and how it will show on your transcript.  It will likely be better than a grade of F.

Answer (score 2):

Failing the class means you hurt your GPA and do not get credit for the class.

Taking an audit grade will not affect your GPA (but check the specific details at your school), though you will not get those five credit hours.

Another option, depending on how far behind you are, could be to take an incomplete and wrap up the class next semester. The details would be negotiated with the instructor. This risks failing the class but would give you some time to study enough to pass. If you pass, you get the five credit hours. I did this once in college, and it was not a big deal. (In a class of 20-30, I was not even the only student who took an incomplete and took the final exam the next semester.)

Medical issues often get special consideration, so there might be even more options if you talk to your instructor or advisor.

Comment: Where I taught, the requirements for a grade of Incomplete were very strict.  It surely wouldn't hurt to ask the professor though.